# I can't work out why "this.driver is null" when running an assertion

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

First time poster so apologies if I'm breaking some guidelines.

I'm teaching myself Java/Selenium/Chromedriver and I've hit the first problem that I haven't been able to work out myself. I'll do my best to represent it below but please ask for more info if I haven't included what I needed to! Here is the test:

```
    @Test
public void loginAsTomSmith(){
    LoginPage loginPage = homePage.clickFormAuthentication();
    loginPage.enterUsername("tomsmith");
    loginPage.enterPassword("SuperSecretPassword!");
    SecureAreaPage secureAreaPage = loginPage.clickLogin();
    secureAreaPage.getBannerText();

    assertTrue(secureAreaPage.getBannerText()
                    .contains("You logged into a secure area!"),"Incorrect message displayed");
}
```

As you can see, I pass the driver from the homepage right over to the login page in my first step (I *think*). I then eventually pass it over to the secureareapage and it's *there* that I get the following error when I run the assertion:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
```

It's notable that I've been following an online course but I'm going rogue for this specific project and doing a few things that I wasn't taught. For example, in the course every page object is a distinct class whereas I've decided to have all pages be an extension of a base page class so they can share basic methods more easily. I'm starting to worry that there have been consequences of that decision that I didn't understand.

Anyway, since the project is so small it probably makes sense to post it in full. Thanks in advance for your help. Huge fan of your work!

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class BasePage{
    protected WebDriver driver;

    protected BasePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    protected void clickLink(By linkTextBy){
        driver.findElement(linkTextBy).click();
    }

    protected void populateTextField(By textFieldBy, String inputText){
        driver.findElement(textFieldBy).sendKeys(inputText);

    }

    protected void clickButton(By buttonBy){
        driver.findElement(buttonBy).click();

    }
}
```

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class HomePage extends BasePage{
//    private WebDriver driver;
    private By formAuthenticationLink = By.linkText("Form Authentication");

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    public LoginPage clickFormAuthentication(){
        clickLink(formAuthenticationLink);
        return new LoginPage(driver);
    }

}
```

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginPage extends BasePage{
    private By usernameTextField= By.id("username");
    private By passwordTextField = By.id("password");
    private By loginButton = By.className("radius");


    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    public void enterUsername(String username){
        populateTextField(usernameTextField, username);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String password){
        populateTextField(passwordTextField, password);
    }

    public SecureAreaPage clickLogin(){
        clickButton(loginButton);
        return new SecureAreaPage(driver);
    }
}
```

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class SecureAreaPage extends BasePage {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private By loginBanner = By.id("flash");

    public SecureAreaPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    public String getBannerText(){
        return driver.findElement(loginBanner).getText();
    }

}
```

```
package base;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import pages.HomePage;

public class BaseTests {
    private WebDriver driver;

        protected HomePage homePage;

        @BeforeClass
        public void setUp(){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");

            homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        }

        @AfterClass
        public void tearDown(){
            driver.quit();
        }
}
```

```
package base;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pages.LoginPage;
import pages.SecureAreaPage;

public class LoginTests extends BaseTests {

    @Test
    public void loginAsTomSmith(){
        LoginPage loginPage = homePage.clickFormAuthentication();
        loginPage.enterUsername("tomsmith");
        loginPage.enterPassword("SuperSecretPassword!");
        SecureAreaPage secureAreaPage = loginPage.clickLogin();
        secureAreaPage.getBannerText();

        assertTrue(secureAreaPage.getBannerText()
                        .contains("You logged into a secure area!"),"Incorrect message displayed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SecureAreaPage` contains a field `private WebDriver driver;` that you never initialize (in the constructor you call `super(driver);` but you never initialize the field in `SecureAreaPage`).

In the method `getBannerText()` you call `driver.findElement(loginBanner)` which accesses the field from `SecureAreaPage`.

Since every subclass of `BasePage` has access to the `driver` field in `BasePage` you do not need hat field. Remove it and everything should work.

The principle behind this is that the field `driver` of the class `SecureAreaPage` "shadows" the field `driver` of the class `BasePage`.

Comment: This was exactly it, thank you so much. I left a rogue driver lying around!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the correct chromedriver.exe for your installed Chrome version?

Some time ago, this was the solution when I encountered this problem.

Take a look at this page:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

> If you are using Chrome version 102, please download ChromeDriver
> 102.0.5005.27
>
> If you are using Chrome version 101, please download ChromeDriver
> 101.0.4951.41
>
> If you are using Chrome version 100, please download ChromeDriver
> 100.0.4896.60